# How to restart a Desktop Bridge app programmatically

Tags: wpf, windows-10-universal, desktop-bridge

I have a Desktop Bridge app which needs to have a "Restart" button.

I've got it calling RequestRestartAsync method on the CoreApplication (described in [this blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/07/28/restart-app-programmatically/#gQS5uXzQAOgrPO2a.97)) - but at runtime it fails with reason "NotInForeground".

I wonder if this is because of the way the Desktop Bridge technology wraps the WPF application. Any ideas on how I can cause the app to restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new feature which is introduced from Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (v10.0.16299.0). Please note that not all UWP APIs are available for desktop bridge apps. You could check this document [UWP APIs available to a packaged desktop app (Desktop Bridge)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api). The `CoreApplication` relevant APIs have not been listed on the document. So, you cannot use this APIs in desktop bridge app now.

Comment: Any plans to make that API available for Desktop Bridge apps? And/or any other suggestions to restart a Desktop Bridge app?

Comment: For the moment, there's no built-in APIs for you to do it. You would have to tell the users to close and restart the app again. You also could submit your "feature request" to [UWP UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/). You could vote it up. MS might think about adding this feature in the later version base on the energy value for this feature request.

Comment: I've added a [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/32353297-make-requestrestartasync-work-in-desktop-bridge-ap) - if you're reading this, please upvote!

Answer (score 0):

You can restart a Desktop Bridge app in the same way you can restart any regular Win32/WPF app. Nothing specific about it being on the "desktop bridge". For example you could spin up a new process, exit the app, and then have the new process launch a new instance of your app (and then kill itself).

I agree we should make the RequestRestartAsync() API work for Desktop Bridge apps as well to make this easier. We have logged a workitem on our backlog based on your UserVoice post.